# how to retrieve All Checked Items from radTreeListView SelectedItems Collection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, telerik, radtreeview

how do i retrieve all Checked Items from a radTreeListView SelectedItems Collection in c#?

The example below from [Retrieve All Checked Items](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreeview-retrieving-checked-items.html) isn't working at all.

```
foreach ( object checkedItem in radTreeView.CheckedItems )
{
    // Get the container(RadTreeViewItem) of the checked item
    RadTreeViewItem container = radTreeView.ContainerFromItemRecursive( checkedItem );
    // Add your logic for handling the checked item scenario here
}
```

The XML for the RadTreeListView is

```
<telerik:RadTreeListView x:Name="radTreeListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectionChanged="radTreeListView_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanging="radTreeListView_SelectionChanging" BeginningEdit="radTreeListView_BeginningEdit">
            <telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
                <telerik:TreeListViewTableDefinition ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
            </telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
            <telerik:RadTreeListView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"   Header="Name" />
                </telerik:RadTreeListView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadTreeListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedItems` is the key!

I prepared SampleData as described [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreeliestview-getting-started.html#Prepare_a_Sample_Data) and capture checked items with following code.

```
 System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object> selected_items = radTreeListView.SelectedItems;
        foreach (object item in selected_items)
        {
            WarehouseItem warehouseitem = (WarehouseItem)item;
            MessageBox.Show(warehouseitem.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Error: Can not resolve symbol 'RadTreeNode', so in which calls/namespace is RadTreeNode in?

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior I check that and understand you are developing in wpf wait i will change answer:) It's different in WPF

Comment: This answer can provide upvotes as well.It takes time and you know it.

Comment: it's working but **item** give me error  _Unable to cast object of type 'Sharegate.Entities.Drive' to type _  in **foreach**

Comment: you should check what type is `Sharegate.Entities.Drive` you may cast it directly to it's type, it's better to post a new question with full text of your code.